# IE not rendering png background image properly

Tags: image, internet-explorer, png, rendering

I have create a PNG arrow graphic for use in a client's website. It render's perfectly everywhere except in IE 6,7,8 and 9. I have attached an image for you to examine and have already tried 2 different IE png fix scripts - one jquery and one a css behaviour .htc file.
Please assist me.
Thanks
Jamie

Image: http://i51.tinypic.com/2w1uzqe.jpg

Comment: Are you trying to use a DX Opacity filter on top of the PNG file? That will cause badness like this. In IE9, you should use the CSS3 Opacity feature.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say that but for 5 years i've been looking for 100% working hack for png transparency bug in IE's with no result. There are many of them and usually each of them doesn't work here and there.

Try using transparent gif instead or crop arrow image with background along. It will take few more bytes of White color so won't damage your performance that much.

Answer (score 0):

The bug that IE PNG Fix scripts are designed to fix is only a problem for IE6 and lower.. hmm.. possibly IE7? I forget. In any case, IE8 fixed the issue, and IE9 *definitely* shouldn't have it. These IE versions may still have plenty of bugs, but the old well known PNG background issue isn't one of them.

My guess is that there may be a corruption in the PNG file itself.

My suggestion is to try loading the PNG image into Photoshop (or your favourite graphics app), and re-save it. That may be all you need to do to solve the issue.

Failing that, would you be able to give us a link to the actual PNG file, so we can have a look as well?